# ATSAM4S PLL LRC filter PCB placement

Tags: passive-networks

I'm designing a simple breakout board based on Atmel SAM4S4A MCU. I've downloaded complete design of ATSAM4S Evaluation board and it says that PLL filter is missing in it and refers to AT03463 Schematic Checklist that shows following schematic of power supplies:

[image: SAM4S Single Power schematic example]

I've got a question in regards to VDD_PLL line, does it matter in what order RLC components are placed or not? Which capacitor should be closest to MCU? 100nF one or 1R+4.7uF one? From my experience I believe that inductor L1 10uH should be connected to resistor and cap and then closest to MCU there should be a 100nF cap? Am I correct? Thanks!

Another example of VDDPLL from SAM4E EVM:

[image]

Here's a cut from ATSAM4S EVM schematic revision 5, in revision 4 there's no such note.

[image]

And this is from SAME70 EVM design documentation, just a ferrite bead and 100nF cap on VDDPLL. I'm completely confused.

[image]

Comment: Does the data sheet show a recommended layout ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I've downloaded several different EVM boards from Atmel, but they're quite different, some have BLM18PG471SN1 right on output of 3.3V regulator and then closer to MCU another one, some doesn't have any filtering at all except for 100nF bypass cap.

Comment: Put the 100 nF at the pins then.

Comment: On EVM schematic of latest revision it says: "NOTE: There is missing an LC filter
on the VDDPLL supply pin in this
schematic.
This may cause problems for the
48MHz PLL to lock and USB
applications may not work.
For more information see AT03463
SAM4S Schematics Checklist."

Comment: Put the 100 nF at the pins then

Comment: There's already 100nF at all pins, the question is about how to put LRC filter correctly on PCB. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be much more concerned about the self-resonant frequency of the inductor than anything else. 56 micro henries is likely to be really poor at rejection above 1 MHz.

Comment: That's in SAM4E but I'm also surprised a bit. For SAM4S it's 10uH as per picture in original post, I don't know how to insert images into comments so have to edit original post.

Comment: In much higher frequency SAME70 design they just put a BLM18PG471SN1 with 100nF cap to VDDPLL line. Not sure if LRC filter should only apply to SAM4S design. To be completely honest I already have another proto board with SAM4S and only a 100nF cap on this pin and it works perfectly fine. But question is more about if I need to put this LRC filter in - what order should components be placed in?

Comment: Which capacitor is closest to the VDDPLL pin? 100nF one or R + 4.7uF? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a picture of a confirmed working design with a ATSAM4S2A. Note that I'm using a 4 layer board and have dedicated power planes. I've also done this with a ATSAM4S4BA and also had successful results.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: In your PCB, what is C42? It looks to be connected in parallel with C46 below L2...

Comment: @Lt_Flash C42 is a 4.7uF bypass capacitor. It goes to the VDDOUT net. It shares the same via as L2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I thought! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem. If you have any other questions about the ATSAM4S, I'd be happy to help.